# python 2D array with linspace

Tags: python

I want to generate 2D array of 1024x1024, start from (275.79905,64.215746) to (275.14172,64.500187) instead of (0,0) to (1024,1024). I know `linspace` can generate it, but how can I make 2D array using it?

Answer (score 5):

I´d suggest using `meshgrid`. Here is the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).

---

#### Example

```
>>> nx, ny = (3, 2)
>>> x = np.linspace(0, 1, nx)
>>> y = np.linspace(0, 1, ny)
>>> xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)
>>> xv
array([[ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ]])
>>> yv
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

---

`linspace` args:

1. Start value
2. Final value
3. Number of all values in the vector

Comment: @OP, for this _particular_ case (n x n), you can `meshgrid` the array with itself: `meshgrid(x, x)`