# How to make a grid equidistance grid from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a matrix of dataframe 128x128 and I want to make it equidistance for interpolation how can I do it? Here is the grid from that data frame and now there are points that are not the same distance.How can I make this uniformly spaced.  [image]

Comment: You question is ambiguous, you should provide an example. Also are you sure this is even always possible?

Comment: Can you not talk about 128 x 128 and give an example of a 3 x 3 matrix and the *equidistance elements out of that matrix*?

Comment: yes equidistance is for example linespace method that makes a list of equally spaced variables. for 3x3 I believe it's possible to do with linespace also

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python 2D array with linspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344758/python-2d-array-with-linspace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this? You can change the number of points as you want, just change `a`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.linspace(0,3,4)
grid = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(a,a))

plt.scatter(grid[:,:,0],grid[:,:,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly, this is what I am looking for, how can I make the same for a given data? if I already have the array?

Comment: What kind of data do you have? Can you give a representative example? What do you mean by "the array"? Do you mean the array 'a' in my code?

Comment: no it's a data that I have which is 128x128. Actually the type is a DataFrame, so what I want to do is to create a grid from that datafram and I want the grid to be equidistance.